Using a generic function with one generic and one concrete type
Trying to get a better grasp of traits and generics, so building a simple tcp server master-slave like library, currently I have this layout
pub struct MyStruct<Output, Stream, Store>
where
    Output: StoreOutput,
    Stream: AsyncStream,
    Store: Storage<Output>,
{
    node: Arc<RwLock<Node<Stream>>>,
    store: Arc<RwLock<Store>>,
    _marker: PhantomData<Output>,
}

impl<Output, Store> MyStruct<Output, TcpStream, Store>
where
    Output: StoreOutput,
    Store: Storage<Output>,
{
    pub async fn run(&self) -> io::Result<()> {
        if let NodeRole::Replica(master) = self.role().await {
            let remote: Connection<TcpStream> = Connection::from_addr(master).await.unwrap();
            let _ = sync(remote, self.node.clone(), self.store.clone()).await;
        }
        let listener = self.node.read().await.listen().await?;
        loop {
            if let Ok((conn, _addr)) = listener.accept().await {
                self.handle(conn);
            }
        }
    }
}


pub async fn sync<Output, Stream, Store>(
    remote: Connection<Stream>,
    node: SharedNode<Stream>,
    store: SharedStore<Store>,
) where
    Output: StoreOutput,
    Stream: AsyncStream,
    Store: Storage<Output>,
{
    
    let (uuid, addr) = {
        let lock = node.read().await;
        (lock.uuid(), lock.addr())
    };

    let (conn, remote_store) = actions::get_subscription(uuid, addr, remote).await.unwrap();
    let _ = store.write().await.initialize::<Store>(remote_store).unwrap();
    let _ = sync_routine::<Output, Stream, Store>(conn, node, store);
}

I understand that calling MyStruct::run() works because the impl uses Stream as a concrete type TcpStream.
So in another function, doing this fails:

async fn handle_cmd<'cmd, Output, Stream, Store>(
    mut conn: net::Connection<Stream>,
    cmd: Command<'cmd>,
    node: SharedNode<Stream>,
    store: SharedStore<Store>,
) -> Result<(), HandleError>
where
    Output: StoreOutput,
    Stream: AsyncStream,
    Store: Storage<Output>,
{
    match &cmd {
        Command::Redirect(args) => {
            let remote = Connection::from_addr(args[0].parse().unwrap()).await.unwrap();
            let node: Arc<RwLock<Node<Stream>>> = Arc::clone(&node);
            let _ = sync(remote, node, store).await;    // FAILS with: mismatched types
                                                        // expected struct `Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<Node<tokio::net::TcpStream>>>`
                                                        // found struct `Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<Node<Stream>>>`
        },
        _ => {}
    }

    Ok(())
}

Since Connection::from_addr returns a Connection<TcpStream> instead of a generic one, and does not match with Node<Stream which is generic, what is the best way to proceed here? should I duplicate the async fn handle_cmd<'cmd, Output, Stream, Store> implementation, one for Stream, Stream and one for TcpStream, TcpStream?

There's so much missing code that it's hard to tell exactly what the problem is, but I suspect that Connection::from_addr returns Connection<TcpStream>. Presumably it would compile if you used two different type parameters for each stream type in sync, one for remote and one for node.

That is correct, from_addr -> Connection<TcpStream>, in order to keep the example short I may have missed a few important traits, here are the main ones:
pub trait IntoBytes { fn into_bytes(self) -> Vec<u8> }
pub trait StoreOutput: Debug + IntoBytes + Send + Sync + 'static {}
pub trait Storage<O: IntoBytes>: Readable<O> + Writable + Serialize + Deserialize + Sized + Send + Sync + 'static {}
pub trait AsyncStream: Debug + AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Unpin + Send + Sync + 'static {}
So I guess using 2 different type params is the correct way of solving this?

Whether it's correct or not depends on a lot of other things in your program that you haven't shown us, but it's probably the first thing I would try.
